# Вставка строк в таблицу с помощью SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

Нужно вставить в таблицу строки от "name/1.png" до "name/1000.png".

Comment: А на каком именно SQL ? на поддерживающих рекурисвные запросы - решаемо, на не поддерживающих - то 1 записи внешним скриптом или хранимой процедурой

Comment: Нужно для SQLite.

Comment: @Mike а `WHILE ... BEGIN ... END` никак в insert'е нельзя использовать?

Comment: А можно пример?

Comment: @Stack В SQL нет while. Есть в реализациях языков для хранимых процедур, но это не sql. и что то сомневаюсь что в SQLlight вообще есть хранимки. сейчас посмотрю что он умеет ...

Comment: @Влад Версия SQLite какая ? вроде рекурсивные поддерживаются после версии 3.8.3

Comment: Версия SQLite 3.8.10.2

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
insert into table
with recursive cnt(x) as (
 VALUES(1)
 union all
select x+1 from cnt where x<1000
)
select 'name/'||x||'.png' from cnt
```

Comment: спасибо большое, навел на мысль

Answer (score 0):

Если количество значений известно, но можно воспользоваться [генерацией числовой последовательности](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_number_sequence_generation.html) без рекурсии.

Comment: Самое главное я, на мой взгляд, указал - это возможность получить последовательность чисел без рекурсивных запросов, которые не все СУБД поддерживают. А если вы имели в виду дать окончательное решение, то увы - я не использую sqlite.